# Problems with plotting augmented images

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, data-augmentation

I'm currently following along deeplizard's blog about Data Augmentation here:

https://deeplizard.com/learn/video/14syUbL16k4

Right now, I'm stuck at a point where I can load my normal image I list just fine, but there seems to just be an empty space when I am suppose to plot the augmented images.

If someone can point out where I've gone wrong in the augmentation process, it would be much appreciated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import random
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
%matplotlib inline

def plotImages(images_arr):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 10, figsize=(20,20))
    axes = axes.flatten()
    for img, ax in zip( images_arr, axes):
        ax.imshow(img)
        ax.axis('off')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    
gen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=10, width_shift_range=0.1, height_shift_range=0.1, shear_range=0.15, zoom_range=0.1, 
    channel_shift_range=10., horizontal_flip=True)

image_path = 'C:/TriangleSquares/triangle.png'

image = np.expand_dims(plt.imread(image_path),0)

plt.imshow(image[0])

aug_iter = gen.flow(image)

aug_images = [next(aug_iter)[0].astype(np.uint8) for i in range(10)]

plotImages(aug_images)
```

[Image of output so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0vbC.png)

Comment: copied and ran your code exactly, it ran fine and generated 10 augmented images. Only difference is I used a different image than you did

Comment: Ah, I think I found the problem -- the image seems to have to be a jpeg.

Comment: The images have be be either jpg, png or tiff since those formats are what the ImageDataGenerator can handle.  png file sould be 3 channels